# Regular Expressions: Match words between two given strings (no blank spaces or similar)

Tags: python, regex, string, regular-language

I am trying to get a regex that is able to get the words, not getting the blank spaces, between two given strings, at this moment I have this one:

```
(?<=STR1)(?:\s*)(.*?)(?:\s*)(?=STR2)
```

I want to use it to get the following results:

```
WORD0 STR1    WORD1 WORD2 WORD3  
WORD4 WORD5 STR2 WORD6
```

I want a regex that matches `WORD1,WORD2,WORD3,WORD4,WORD5`

PS: I am working with python, and thank you

Comment: Why aren't `WORD0` and `WORD6` in the intended output? By *between two given strings* you mean between `WORD0` and `WORD6`?

Comment: It would probably make sense to first isolate your range by finding `STR1` and `STR2`, and then run simply run a `split`. What I'm saying is that regex may not be the best tool for the job here. You could use regex to find the range to split, though.

Comment: Edited the question, I want every word between the STRX, but I cannot use string methods, because the communication between the device and the client.

Comment: `"I cannot use string methods, because the communication between the device and the client"`

Can you elaborate on what that means? Why doesn't regex count as a string method when it operates on strings?

Comment: It is for an old software for telecommunications, if I could work with string split I wouldn't be asking this, anyway as the question title says, I am asking if there is any solution that implies regex.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot do that with `re` because 1) it does not support unknown length lookbehind patterns and 2) it has no support for `\G` operator that can be used to match strings in between two strings.

So, what you can do is `pip install regex`, and then use

```py
import regex
text = "WORD0 STR1    WORD1 WORD2 WORD3  \nWORD4 WORD5 STR2 WORD6"
print( regex.findall(r"(?<=STR1.*)\w+(?=.*STR2)", text, regex.DOTALL) )
# => ['WORD1', 'WORD2', 'WORD3', 'WORD4', 'WORD5']
```

See the [Python demo](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/7/PzO3IL@oRKEoNT21gqsktaJEwVZBKdw/yMVAITgkyFABCEA8QzBpBCaNFRRi8kAMEzDXFKQQImOmxFVQlJlXogExTy8tMy8lMSdHo0hJw97GFmSenpZmTLm2hr2tnhZIl6aSjgLIUh2oBhf/EEcfH00Fzf//AQ). *Details*:

- `(?<=STR1.*)` - a positive lookbehind matching `STR1` and any zero or more chars immediately to the left of the current location
- `\w+` - one or more word chars
- `(?=.*STR2)` - a positive lookahead matching any zero or more chars and `STR2` immediately to the right of the current location.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming `'STR1'` and `'STR2'` are known to be present you can write the following

```
str = "WORD0 STR1    WORD1 WORD2 WORD3\nWORD4 WORD5 STR2 WORD6"
```

```
rgx = r'\b(?!.*\bSTR1\b)\w+(?=.*\bSTR2\b)'
```

```
re.findall(rgx, str, re.S) 
  #=> ['WORD1', 'WORD2', 'WORD3', 'WORD4', 'WORD5']
```

`re.S` (same as `re.DOTALL`) causes periods to match all characters, including line terminators.

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/OWBMOZ/1)<sup><sub><-</sub></sup><sub>\(ツ)/</sub><sup><sub>-></sub></sup>[Python demo](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/7/PzO3IL@oRKEolYuruKRIwVZBSUkp3D/IxUAhOCTIUAEIQDxDMGkEJo0VFLhAtAmYZwpSB5EwA2rlAungKkqvAJpUpB6TpGGvqKcVkwQyKyZJM6ZcW8PeFipgBBRQ5@IqKMrMK9EoStVLy8xLSczJ0QBq1lEAukUH6Ci9YE1NBa7//wE)

The regular expression can be broken down as follows.

```
\b          # match a word boundary
(?!         # begin a negative lookahead
  .*        # match zero or more characters
  \bSTR1\b  # match 'STR1' with word boundaries
)           # end negative lookahead
\w+         # match zero or more word characters
(?=         # begin a positive lookahead
  .*        # match zero or more characters
  \bSTR1\b  # match 'STR2' with word boundaries
)           # end positive lookahead
```

Note that the negative lookahead ensures that the matched word (`\w+`) is not followed by `'STR1'`, in which case it must be preceded by that string.

Depending on requirements, `\w+` might replaced with `[A-Z]+\d+` or something else.

Also note that the word boundary (`\b`) at the beginning of the expression is to avoid matching `'TR1'`.